# Analytic continuation in plane isomorphic to $\Bbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, recreational-mathematics, infinite-product, analytic-continuation

Define $\varphi(s)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \exp\big(n^{-s}\big)$ where $s=\exp a + i\exp b$ for $a,b \in \Bbb R.$

> Does there exist an analytic continuation of $\varphi(s)?$

For *real* $s>1$ the product converges.

I'm wondering if there's an analytic continuation of $\varphi(s)$ and what it is in terms of familiar functions.

The space of numbers, $s$ forms a plane isomorphic to $\Bbb C.$

Comment: Isn’t your $\varphi(s)$ just equal to $\exp{\zeta(s)}$?

Comment: yeah - does that mean I can just substitute $s=\exp a + i \exp b $ into, $\exp \zeta(s)?$

Comment: If $\text{Re}(s)>1$, then the infinite product converges to $\varphi(s)=\exp\zeta(s)$ as mentioned above. On the other hand, we know $\zeta$ is analytic on $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$, so the composite function $\exp\circ \zeta$ on the RHS is analytic on $\Bbb{C}\setminus \{1\}$. Thus, $\exp\circ \zeta$ analytically continues $\varphi$ to $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$.

Comment: it seems like it doesn't matter for the analytic continuation whether $s=a+ib$ or $s=\exp a +i \exp b$. Is that correct?

Comment: yes that's right. As long as $s\neq 1$, you're fine.